# <canvas> restoring problems

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I tried to use the canvas tag to allow users to draw shapes, but drawing a new line causes all other lines to disappear. [Try It (copy+paste to the textarea and click the "Edit and Click Me >>" button)](http://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_basic). I should mention that this problem exists in all 5 most popular browser (including IE7,8 and IE9beta).

The code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<!-- ... -->
<!-- (a script used to support canvas in IE7,8) --><!--[if lte IE 8]>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://explorercanvas.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/excanvas.js"></script>
<![endif]-->
<script type="text/javascript">//<![CDATA[
    var cnvs, cntxt;
    window.onload = function () {
        cnvs = document.getElementById("cnvs");
        cntxt = cnvs.getContext("2d");
        //...
    };

    var lastX, lastY;
    function beginLine(x, y) {
        cntxt.moveTo(x, y);
        cntxt.save();
        lastX = x;
        lastY = y;
        cnvs.setAttribute("onmousemove", "preview(event.clientX, event.clientY);");
        cnvs.setAttribute("onmouseup", "closeLine(event.clientX, event.clientY);");
    }

    function closeLine(x, y) {
        cntxt.lineTo(x, y);
        cntxt.stroke();
        cntxt.save();
        cnvs.removeAttribute("onmousemove");
        cnvs.removeAttribute("onmouseup");
    }

    function preview(x, y) {
        cntxt.beginPath();
        cntxt.clearRect(0, 0, cnvs.width, cnvs.height);
        cntxt.restore();
        cntxt.moveTo(lastX, lastY);
        cntxt.lineTo(x, y);
        cntxt.stroke();
    }
//]]></script>
</head>
<body>
    <!-- ... -->
    <canvas id="cnvs" style="position:absolute;top:0;left:0;border:1px black solid;" onmousedown="beginLine(event.clientX, event.clientY);"></canvas>
    <p style="margin-top:200px;">(click and drag the mouse to draw a line)</p>
</body>
</html>
```

It's probably a save/restore mistake, but I can't find it.

---

I have tried 2 different forums:

- [w3schools](http://w3schools.invisionzone.com/index.php?showtopic=34999)
- [MSDN](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/netfxjscript/thread/863927cb-ef90-43d7-9833-8c3d77c53c74)

but nobody could tell what the problem is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You misunderstood the meaning of *save* and *restore* methods. They save canvas *state* not content. 
Meaning, when you issue canvas.save() you are saving *fillStyle*, *strokeStyle*, *lineWidth* and *lineJoin*.

Simplest solution to your problem is to keep another canvas of the same size in memory and then once mouse button is released, *clearRect* and use *drawImage* method. Or you can push lines to an array and redraw them each time (which might be faster than drawing another canvas over existing one).

Additionally, another tip regarding *clearRect*. It turns out, this method is incredibly slow. In your case you are not using it often enough to have some significant impact on performance but it is much faster to assign same *width* and *height* to canvas object.

Comment: You might especially mention `save` saving transforms (rotate, translate, and scale).